# How to compute $H^1(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1})$ and $H^1(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}(n))$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, homology-cohomology, quasicoherent-sheaves

Let $\mathcal{O}_{\Bbb P^1}$ be the structure sheaf of the projective line $X=\Bbb P^1_k$ over some field $k$ (algebraically closed of characteristic $0$). What is a good (and, preferably, easy) way to compute the cohomology group $H^1(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}_X)$?

I thought about taking the affine open cover consisting of $U_0=\{x_0\neq 0\}$ and $U_1=\{x_1\neq 0\}$ and using the exact skyscraper sequence
$$0\to\mathcal{O}_X(-1)\to\mathcal{O}_X\to k_p\to 0,$$
where $p=(1:0)$. Here $\varphi\in\mathcal{O}_X(-1)(U)$ is mapped to $x_0\varphi\in\mathcal{O}_X(U)$, while $\mathcal{O}_X(U_0)\ni\psi\mapsto \psi(p)\in k_p(U_0)=k$.

Then we get a long exact cohomology sequence
$$0\to \Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(-1))\to\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X)\to\Gamma(k_p)\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X(-1))\to H^1(\mathcal{O}_X)\to H^1(k_p)\to 0.$$
Using $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X(-1))=0$, $\Gamma(\mathcal{O}_X)=k=\Gamma(k_p)$, and $H^1(k_p)$ should be zero, too, since by definition $C^1(k_p)=\prod_{i<j}k_p(U_i\cap U_j)=k_p(U_0\cap U_1)=0$. This simplifies the sequence a bit, but I don't know how to proceed from here.

Is there another way to compute the cohomology group (which should be $0$), maybe even without the long exact sequence? If yes, I could maybe use this to also prove $H^1(\Bbb P^1,\mathcal{O}_X(n))=\{x_0^ix_1^j:i+j=n,i<0,j<0\}$.

**Edit:** Just to be more precise, I'm talking about a variety point-of-view here, not scheme-theoretic, although I hope this shouldn't make much difference :)

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can try computing via the Cech complex, similarly to Hartshorne's Example III.4.0.3. (Also, the cohomology of (twists of the structure sheaf on) projective space is the subject of III.5.)

Comment: @Andrew: Okay, I thought Hartshorne wasn't 'made' for me, since we never used schemes in this lecture, but maybe the computations are similiar. Gonna check them out, thanks :)

Comment: Dear Rand, actually, I don't think you really need to know what a scheme is for this part of Hartshorne!

Comment: @Randal'Thor: there is no difference between algebraic variety and scheme approaches for this computation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the comments above suggest, it is proven in Hartshorne III, Theorem 5.1 that $H^n( \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}}(m))$ is the $k$-vector space with basis equal to the monomials $x_0^{l_0}...x_n^{l_n}$ where $l_i$ are all negative and sum to $-m$.   This of course implies that $H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}}) = H^1(\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}}(0)) = 0$.

The trick of the calculation is to compute the cohomology of $\bigoplus_{m} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{k}^{n}}(m)$ while keeping track of the grading.